# Eigen: Extracting a block misses some entries

Tags: eigen

I try to take a block in Eigen:

```
Eigen::VectorXi v = Eigen::VectorXi::Zero(20);
v << 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 16, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0;
cout << "v = " << v << endl;
v = v.block(0, 0, 16, 1);
cout << "v = "<< v << endl;
```

Strangely, the first two entries in `v` will be zero after taking the block.

The output of the program looks as follows:

```
v =  7 # start original vector from here
10
11
14
15
16
16
 1
 2
 3
 2
 3
 4
 5
 4
 5
 0
 0
 0
 0
v =  0 # start block out of vector, why zero here?
 0
11
14
15
16
16
 1
 2
 3
 2
 3
 4
 5
 4
 5
```

What's going wrong here? **Could this be a bug in Eigen or did I missunderstand something from the documentation?**

Answer (score 5):

You are experiencing an aliasing problem: `v` gets resized before `v.block(...)` gets assigned to the new `v`. There are two solutions:

- Evaluate into a temporary using `.eval()`:

  ```
  v = v.block(0,0,16,1).eval();  // or
  v = v.head(16).eval(); // shorter but equivalent
  ```
- Or, use `conservativeResize()` (but only works if you want to keep the top-left corner):

  ```
  v.conservativeResize(16);
  ```

For further reference [this page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicAliasing.html) summarizes some common aliasing pitfalls (it also mentions the resizing alias you experienced).

Comment: Isn't this behavior a bit strange from a semantic point of view? `v = v.something(...)` has a pretty clear meaning, and I think it's very unfortunate that such strange things can happen. So it should be implemented that it always does the "right" thing or it should be prohibited at all by not supporting the overload. That's my current semi-educated point of view, but I'd be interested what else might be behind.

Comment: This is a general problem with aliasing. You also get a problem when assigning `v.tail(16)=v.head(16);` and detecting every such case would generate unecessary overhead in situations where it is not needed.